# Insert an XML tag into another another tag

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am trying to iterate through one XML file in Python with ElementTree, change one attribute in a tag and then insert that tag into another tag in another file, code below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('original_file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
cnt = 1


exact = ET.Element("eExact")
glentries = ET.SubElement(exact, "GLEntries")
glentry = ET.SubElement(glentries, "GLEntry", status="E", entry="194100751")

ET.SubElement(glentry, "DocumentDate").text = "31032019"
ET.SubElement(glentry, "Description").text = "TEST"

ET.SubElement(glentry, "Journal", code="41", type="M")

for child in root.iter('FinEntryLine'):
    child.attrib["number"] = cnt
    ET.SubElement(glentry, child)
    cnt += 1

tree = ET.ElementTree(exact)
tree.write("output_file.xml")
```

However this does not work, because ElemntTree and SubElement are reporting that they can't serialiaze. Is there another way in doing it, but so I do not have to iterate though all the subtags of "child"?

Input file:

```
<eExact>
   <GLEntries>
     <GLEntry status="E" entry="194100751">
       <DocumentDate>31032019</DocumentDate>
       <Description>TEST</Description>
       <Journal code="41" type="M"></Journal>

  <FinEntryLine number="83932" type="N" subtype="N">
    <Description>01032019 GWPC 1900005105</Description>
  </FinEntryLine>
  <FinEntryLine number="98457" type="N" subtype="N">
    <Description>01032019 GWPC 1900005105</Description>
  </FinEntryLine>

  </GLEntry>
  </GLEntries>
</eExact>
```

Output should just change number tag into sequence, starting from 1.

Comment: The question is unclear. Are there two XML files involved? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi mzjn, I have added the full code, please note that I have specifically said "another file" in my explanation which implies there are two files.

Comment: I think @mzjn was asking if there were two input XML files. There doesn’t appear to be. Can you please add an example input XML and desired output? That would give us something complete to reproduce your issue and suggest an appropriate fix.

Comment: I literally want to copy a specific tag from one file, which is in "child" in the for loop and put insert it into the second file as a subgroup of SubElement "glentry". However ET.SubElement can't be used for it, but I can't find which procedure should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the `number` attribute of the `<FinEntryLine>` elements, this is all that is needed:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('original_file.xml')
cnt = 1

for child in tree.iter('FinEntryLine'):
    child.attrib["number"] = str(cnt)
    cnt += 1

tree.write("output_file.xml")
```

Result (output_file.xml):

```
<eExact>
   <GLEntries>
     <GLEntry entry="194100751" status="E">
       <DocumentDate>31032019</DocumentDate>
       <Description>TEST</Description>
       <Journal code="41" type="M" />

  <FinEntryLine number="1" subtype="N" type="N">
    <Description>01032019 GWPC 1900005105</Description>
  </FinEntryLine>
  <FinEntryLine number="2" subtype="N" type="N">
    <Description>01032019 GWPC 1900005105</Description>
  </FinEntryLine>

  </GLEntry>
  </GLEntries>
</eExact>
```

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot now, I have totally overthought the solution. Thanks